# InvocationTargetException while hitting rest service in camel route

Tags: apache-camel

I am using camel vs2.9.0 in my project and trying to hit a Rest service.

My route is as mentioned below:

```
<route>
<from uri="direct:restRoute"/>
<bean ref="finalProcess"/>
<setHeader headerName="CamelHttpMethod"><constant>POST</constant></setHeader>
<to uri="http rest service url here"/>
```

finalProcess is just a bean in which I am doing like this :

```
System.out.println(exchange.getIn().toString());
```

I am able to put a json request on the route which gets printed on the above sysout code
, but I am getting following error when it reaches to uri="" step.

```
WARNING : WebApplicationException has been caught : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

Comment: Few questions 

1.  What is `<to uri="finalProcess"/>`? Should that not be `bean:finalProcess`? 
2.  can you post this bean? 
3. What is the value in the last 'to`?

Comment: Sry that was a bean ref.updated above.Last to is a htp rest url.

Comment: Could you edit your post and add the information?

Comment: and the value of the 'to' url?

Comment: 'to' is a rest service of my organization which i am able to hit using soapui but not through camel

Comment: something like `http:host/etc`?

Comment: Yes. http://mycompany.com/someresource

Comment: tx And can you post the whole stacktrace

Comment: I was not printing stacktrace as camel was catching it itself.looked into it more and found that i am missing commons-codec jar which is dependency of httpclient. Thanks for guiding me in write direction.

Comment: good to hear you solved it...not sure if i helped you much. Talk "Rubber duck debugging" sometimes does miracles!